# How to convert array to SimpleXML

Tags: php, xml, arrays, simplexml

How can I convert an array to a SimpleXML object in PHP?

Comment: An array of what?

Comment: This is cool: http://www.viper007bond.com/2011/06/29/easily-create-xml-in-php-using-a-data-array/

Answer (score 227, accepted):

a short one:

```
<?php

$test_array = array (
  'bla' => 'blub',
  'foo' => 'bar',
  'another_array' => array (
    'stack' => 'overflow',
  ),
);
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<root/>');
array_walk_recursive($test_array, array ($xml, 'addChild'));
print $xml->asXML();
```

results in

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <blub>bla</blub>
  <bar>foo</bar>
  <overflow>stack</overflow>
</root>
```

keys and values are swapped - you could fix that with `array_flip()` before the array_walk. `array_walk_recursive` requires PHP 5. you could use `array_walk` instead, but you won't get `'stack' => 'overflow'` in the xml then.

Comment: This won't work if $test_array has 'more_another_array' like 'another_array', because key 'another_array' is not converted. Hence you'll have multiple '<overflow>stack</overflow>'.

Comment: The `array_flip` won't work as it can't flip arrays (like the `another_array` inside the main array).

Comment: Where's the "another_array" xml element ? Everything is flatten down :(

Comment: @FMaz008 Yes, this short version is flattening down multidimensional arrays. For a version that correctly converts these arrays to XML (but is longer), see onokazu's answer below.

Comment: This solution is bad if you want your xml to match the key=>value pairings of the array. array_walk_recursive passes vars to addChild($value, $key), while you actually need them passed as addChild($key, $value). The result is your xml nodes will look like <value>key</value>, which is not how I would ever want my xml to appear. Totally the opposite of how I would have expected it. I suppose you can manipulate this if you do what @ax does and have your array($value => $key), which again is backwards as far as i'm concerned.

Comment: Worked great when I added array_flip before array_walk_recursive. thanks.

Comment: Downvoting because `array_flip` only works if the array contains no identical values.

Comment: Downvoted. Flipping keys/values doesn't work, as values aren't unique, and would overwrite eachother. Also trying to flip a multi-dimensional array crashes PHP with a 'warning'.

Comment: Not working here either. best solution so far: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23087690/514629

Comment: Terrible solution due to the backwards format. Makes no sense at all.

Comment: Down-voting - because, wile superficially elegant, the need to array_flip makes this pretty useless.

Comment: Downvoting, the multidimensial array is not being added, where is `another_array`?

Comment: Downvoting because How the **** a non working solution is signed as top? Who needs to convert an xml that is not multidimensional!?

Answer (score 424):

Here is php 5.2 code which will convert array of any depth to xml document:

```
Array
(
    ['total_stud']=> 500
    [0] => Array
        (
            [student] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => abc
                    [address] => Array
                        (
                            [city]=>Pune
                            [zip]=>411006
                        )                       
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [student] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [name] => xyz
                    [address] => Array
                        (
                            [city]=>Mumbai
                            [zip]=>400906
                        )   
                )

        )
)
```

generated XML would be as:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<student_info>
    <total_stud>500</total_stud>
    <student>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>abc</name>
        <address>
            <city>Pune</city>
            <zip>411006</zip>
        </address>
    </student>
    <student>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>abc</name>
        <address>
            <city>Mumbai</city>
            <zip>400906</zip>
        </address>
    </student>
</student_info>
```

PHP snippet

```
<?php
// function defination to convert array to xml
function array_to_xml( $data, &$xml_data ) {
    foreach( $data as $key => $value ) {
        if( is_array($value) ) {
            if( is_numeric($key) ){
                $key = 'item'.$key; //dealing with <0/>..<n/> issues
            }
            $subnode = $xml_data->addChild($key);
            array_to_xml($value, $subnode);
        } else {
            $xml_data->addChild("$key",htmlspecialchars("$value"));
        }
     }
}

// initializing or creating array
$data = array('total_stud' => 500);

// creating object of SimpleXMLElement
$xml_data = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0"?><data></data>');

// function call to convert array to xml
array_to_xml($data,$xml_data);

//saving generated xml file; 
$result = $xml_data->asXML('/file/path/name.xml');

?>
```

[Documentation on `SimpleXMLElement::asXML` used in this snippet](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asxml.php)

Comment: we used this 'echo $xml_student_info->asXML();' to display this xml directly but it work for large array data. when array data is less then ten element then xml format is not display but only simple format. we used this function header ("Content-type: text/xml"); to display format in xml.

Comment: If you want to have multiple nodes with the same name (as I did), take a look at revision 2. The code forces "item##" tags to get inserted as it stands now.

Comment: @Mifas I have further modified your modified version of Hanmant's answers for shorter code. http://pastebin.com/046N0Cit

Comment: This example explicitly escapes special characters in element text data using htmlspecialchars, but SimpleXMLElement::addChild translates xml special characters to their char entities automatically so htmlspecialchars can be left out. Interestingly, this seems _not_ to result in doubly-escaped data.

Comment: Empty Array-values [(string)""] will be changed to an empty SimpleXML-Node instead of being left empty.

Comment: It would be a good idea to type-hint $student_info as array in the function definition :)

Comment: @Alex, your Edit #5 makes the example fail.  It inserts <item$x> before each <student> record making the XML output not what the author intended. Maybe provide an example of the issue you're trying to fix and we can find another solution for both cases. Took me a while before I realized the authors code was modified.

Comment: After trying so many options, this perfectly was a fit for me, thanks for the same.

Comment: If city is empty it returned <city/> but after adding  `if($value=='') $value='  '; $object->addChild($key, $value);` in last else statement it returned <city></city>

Comment: How can I parse it back to an array in JS? my server does not have JSON and therefore I am stranded with XML.

Comment: I think the correct structure of multiple items with same key should be: 1st is the node name key, then it contains the array with numerical keys, it is logically more correct (the opposite as proposed in this answer).

Comment: @PegLeg3941 Which revision are you talking about? Can you link to it please?

Comment: How can I get rid of the itemxxx node?

Comment: Should post two answers, this modified answer broke my requests as it added `<itemN></itemN>`. This revision: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/5965940/2 was my winner

Comment: What if i wanted to add attributes? how would that look in the array?

Comment: This not working for me. The index number of the array takes as an element and name it like <intem1, <intem2>.. which is not right.

Comment: I made an update for duplicate keys.  if( is_numeric($key) ){
                    if(count($value)==1){
                        $key = array_keys($value)[0];
                        $value = $value[$key];
                        $xml_data->addChild("$key",htmlspecialchars("$value"));
                        continue;
                    }else{
                        $key = 'item'.$key; //dealing with <0/>..<n/> issues
                    }                   
                }

Comment: please change `$xml_data->addChild("$key",htmlspecialchars("$value"));` to `$xml_data->addAttribute("$key",htmlspecialchars("$value"));`

Comment: How would you serialize this? I am getting an error in the xml response "unable to serialize result"

Answer (score 145):

The answers provided here only convert array to XML with nodes, you are not able to set attributes. I have written a php function that allows you to convert an array to php and also set attributes for particular nodes in the xml. The downside here is you have to construct an array in a particular way with few conventions (only if you want to use attributes)

The following example will allow you to set attributes in XML too.

The source can be found here:
https://github.com/digitickets/lalit/blob/master/src/Array2XML.php

```
<?php    
$books = array(
    '@attributes' => array(
        'type' => 'fiction'
    ),
    'book' => array(
        array(
            '@attributes' => array(
                'author' => 'George Orwell'
            ),
            'title' => '1984'
        ),
        array(
            '@attributes' => array(
                'author' => 'Isaac Asimov'
            ),
            'title' => 'Foundation',
            'price' => '$15.61'
        ),
        array(
            '@attributes' => array(
                'author' => 'Robert A Heinlein'
            ),
            'title' => 'Stranger in a Strange Land',
            'price' => array(
                '@attributes' => array(
                    'discount' => '10%'
                ),
                '@value' => '$18.00'
            )
        )
    )
);
/* creates 
<books type="fiction">
  <book author="George Orwell">
    <title>1984</title>
  </book>
  <book author="Isaac Asimov">
    <title>Foundation</title>
    <price>$15.61</price>
  </book>
  <book author="Robert A Heinlein">
    <title>Stranger in a Strange Land</title>
    <price discount="10%">$18.00</price>
  </book>
</books>
*/
?>
```

Comment: I'm supprised that no one reacted on this one. This class is really useful as it's doing the opposite of what's simpleXMLElement will generate. So it gives you the possibility of using SimpleXMLElement both ways.

Comment: I would mark it as answer instead of current. Current answer not building recursive arrays

Comment: Nice class. I changed line 128 `if(!is_array($arr)) {` to `if(!is_array($arr) && $arr !== '') {` so that it won't append a new text node for empty strings and therefore keeps the shorthand empty tag format i.e. `'tag'=>''` is `<tag/>` instead of `<tag></tag>`

Comment: This is the best answer so far. Also this has the correct structure of multiple items with same key: 1st is the node name key, then it contains the array with numerical keys. (the opposite of the Hanmant answer)

Comment: The link to the class is now not working? It is generating a `Error establishing a database connection` error when loading the page. Are you able to repost the class somewhere?

This is exactly what I am looking for, with the only exception being that I cant access the class to use it.

Comment: Found a github from the author  @Legionar

https://github.com/digitickets/lalit/blob/master/src/Array2XML.php

Comment: The link is still broken. I have updated the post to point at the repo @DarylTeo located.

Answer (score 69):

I found all of the answers to use too much code. Here is an easy way to do it:

```php
function to_xml(SimpleXMLElement $object, array $data) {
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        // if the key is an integer, it needs text with it to actually work.
        $valid_key  = is_numeric($key) ? "key_$key" : $key;
        $new_object = $object->addChild( 
            $valid_key, 
            is_array($value) ? null : htmlspecialchars($value) 
        );

        if (is_array($value)) {
            to_xml($new_object, $value);
        }
    }
}
```

Then it's a simple matter of sending the array into the function, which uses recursion, so it will handle a multi-dimensional array:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<rootTag/>');
to_xml($xml, $my_array);
```

Now $xml contains a beautiful XML object based on your array exactly how you wrote it.

```
print $xml->asXML();
```

Comment: I love this solution the most. Although, it would be nice to add a test on numeric keys, like: `if ( is_numeric( $key ) ) $key = "numeric_$key"; `.

Comment: @wout Good catch. Added. I did an int cast check instead of is_numeric because is_numeric can give some, although technically expected, results that would really throw you off.

Comment: I use this function, but changed `$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><rootTag/>');` for valid UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: I like this solution the most as well, simple does it :-)  

One remark:  

You might want  to change `$object->addChild($key, $value);` to `$object->addChild($key, htmlspecialchars($value));` to prevent it from failing when $value contains characters like "&" that need XML-encoding.

Comment: It works, but you have to add  triple equals sign instead:
```if ($key === (int) $key) {
                $key = "key_$key"; }```

Comment: @Valeri with an ===, that would leave you open to numbers as a string attempting to create an array key, which would fail. That's why it cannot do a type check.

Comment: @FrancisLewis ('foobar' == (int) 'foobar') is true anyway, as a result all keys will be prefixed with "key_", which is incorrect.

Comment: @Valeri no. Have you tried running that in PHP? It evaluates to false.

Comment: @FrancisLewis yes, I have and it's true.  ```var_dump('foobar' == (int)'foobar');```

Comment: @Valeri Not sure what I tested yesterday that evaluated to false, so you are correct on this last one. That said, you're only partially correct on the code above. If you set it to ===, it will always give you false, which is also not what you want. I'm editing the code above with what works.

Comment: @FrancisLewis you're right. You should replace that with ```is_numeric($key)```

Answer (score 40):

```
function array_to_xml(array $data, SimpleXMLElement $xml)
{
    foreach ($data as $name => $value) {
        is_array($value)
            ? array_to_xml($value, $xml->addChild($name ))
            : $xml->addChild($name, $value);
    }
    
    return $xml;
}
    
$data = [
    'bla' => 'blub',
    'foo' => 'bar',
    'another_array' => [
        'stack' => 'overflow',
    ],
];

echo array_to_xml($data, new SimpleXMLElement('<root/>'))->asXML();
```

Comment: this fails if your array contains an inner array with numeric indexes. <0>...</0> is not valid XML.

Comment: @AdrianoVaroliPiazza just add something like `$k = (is_numeric($k)) ? 'item' : $k;` inside the `foreach()`

Comment: If one of the keys in the array is named "body", it doesn't work -- more precisely, the key is ignored and traversed. Trying to figure out why.

Comment: @Bambax The only reason I can think of is if the XML is being parsed as HTML at some later point.

Answer (score 19):

From PHP 5.4

```
function array2xml($data, $root = null){
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($root ? '<' . $root . '/>' : '<root/>');
    array_walk_recursive($data, function($value, $key)use($xml){
        $xml->addChild($key, $value);
    });
    return $xml->asXML();
}
```

Comment: It seems like a straight copy from the selected answer, just put into a function.

Comment: I would add htmlspecialchars() to the addChild part, like this: $xml->addChild($key, htmlspecialchars($value));

Answer (score 15):

Another improvement:

```
/**
* Converts an array to XML
*
* @param array $array
* @param SimpleXMLElement $xml
* @param string $child_name
*
* @return SimpleXMLElement $xml
*/
public function arrayToXML($array, SimpleXMLElement $xml, $child_name)
{
    foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
        if(is_array($v)) {
            (is_int($k)) ? $this->arrayToXML($v, $xml->addChild($child_name), $v) : $this->arrayToXML($v, $xml->addChild(strtolower($k)), $child_name);
        } else {
            (is_int($k)) ? $xml->addChild($child_name, $v) : $xml->addChild(strtolower($k), $v);
        }
    }

    return $xml->asXML();
}
```

Usage:

```
$this->arrayToXML($array, new SimpleXMLElement('<root/>'), 'child_name_to_replace_numeric_integers');
```

Comment: Thank you! Your function returns the exact content of any n-dimensional array.

Answer (score 12):

Here is my entry, simple and clean..

```
function array2xml($array, $xml = false){
    if($xml === false){
        $xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<root/>');
    }
    foreach($array as $key => $value){
        if(is_array($value)){
            array2xml($value, $xml->addChild($key));
        }else{
            $xml->addChild($key, $value);
        }
    }
    return $xml->asXML();
}


header('Content-type: text/xml');
print array2xml($array);
```

Answer (score 9):

So anyway... I took onokazu's code (thanks!) and added the ability to have repeated tags in XML, it also supports attributes, hope someone finds it useful!

```
 <?php

function array_to_xml(array $arr, SimpleXMLElement $xml) {
        foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {

            $attrArr = array();
            $kArray = explode(' ',$k);
            $tag = array_shift($kArray);

            if (count($kArray) > 0) {
                foreach($kArray as $attrValue) {
                    $attrArr[] = explode('=',$attrValue);                   
                }
            }

            if (is_array($v)) {
                if (is_numeric($k)) {
                    array_to_xml($v, $xml);
                } else {
                    $child = $xml->addChild($tag);
                    if (isset($attrArr)) {
                        foreach($attrArr as $attrArrV) {
                            $child->addAttribute($attrArrV[0],$attrArrV[1]);
                        }
                    }                   
                    array_to_xml($v, $child);
                }
            } else {
                $child = $xml->addChild($tag, $v);
                if (isset($attrArr)) {
                    foreach($attrArr as $attrArrV) {
                        $child->addAttribute($attrArrV[0],$attrArrV[1]);
                    }
                }
            }               
        }

        return $xml;
    }

        $test_array = array (
          'bla' => 'blub',
          'foo' => 'bar',
          'another_array' => array (
            array('stack' => 'overflow'),
            array('stack' => 'overflow'),
            array('stack' => 'overflow'),
          ),
          'foo attribute1=value1 attribute2=value2' => 'bar',
        );  

        $xml = array_to_xml($test_array, new SimpleXMLElement('<root/>'))->asXML();

        echo "$xml\n";
        $dom = new DOMDocument;
        $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;
        $dom->loadXML($xml);
        $dom->formatOutput = TRUE;
        echo $dom->saveXml();
    ?>
```

Comment: Might be helpful to comment your changes to make the code clearer; still, nice addition

Comment: This worked for me with WP All Export. 

I had to change the is_numeric part slightly:

   `if (is_numeric($k)) {
 $i = $k + 1;
 $child = $xml->addChild("_$i");
        array_to_xml($v, $child);
   }`

Answer (score 5):

I wanted a code that will take all the elements inside an array and treat them as attributes, and all arrays as sub elements.

So for something like

```
array (
'row1' => array ('head_element' =>array("prop1"=>"some value","prop2"=>array("empty"))),
"row2"=> array ("stack"=>"overflow","overflow"=>"overflow")
);
```

I would get something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<someRoot>
  <row1>
    <head_element prop1="some value">
      <prop2 0="empty"/>
    </head_element>
  </row1>
  <row2 stack="overflow" overflow="stack"/>
 </someRoot>
```

To achive this the code is below, but be very careful, it is recursive and may actually cause a stackoverflow :)

```
function addElements(&$xml,$array)
{
$params=array();
foreach($array as $k=>$v)
{
    if(is_array($v))
        addElements($xml->addChild($k), $v);
    else $xml->addAttribute($k,$v);
}

}
function xml_encode($array)
{
if(!is_array($array))
    trigger_error("Type missmatch xml_encode",E_USER_ERROR);
$xml=new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version=\'1.0\' encoding=\'utf-8\'?><'.key($array).'/>');
addElements($xml,$array[key($array)]);
return $xml->asXML();
}
```

You may want to add checks for length of the array so that some element get set inside the data part and not as an attribute.

Answer (score 4):

I use a couple of functions that I wrote a while back to generate the xml to pass back and forth from PHP and jQuery etc... 
Neither use any additional frameworks just purely generates a string that can then be used with SimpleXML (or other framework)...

If it's useful to anyone, please use it :)

```
function generateXML($tag_in,$value_in="",$attribute_in=""){
    $return = "";
    $attributes_out = "";
    if (is_array($attribute_in)){
        if (count($attribute_in) != 0){
            foreach($attribute_in as $k=>$v):
                $attributes_out .= " ".$k."=\"".$v."\"";
            endforeach;
        }
    }
    return "<".$tag_in."".$attributes_out.((trim($value_in) == "") ? "/>" : ">".$value_in."</".$tag_in.">" );
}

function arrayToXML($array_in){
    $return = "";
    $attributes = array();
    foreach($array_in as $k=>$v):
        if ($k[0] == "@"){
            // attribute...
            $attributes[str_replace("@","",$k)] = $v;
        } else {
            if (is_array($v)){
                $return .= generateXML($k,arrayToXML($v),$attributes);
                $attributes = array();
            } else if (is_bool($v)) {
                $return .= generateXML($k,(($v==true)? "true" : "false"),$attributes);
                $attributes = array();
            } else {
                $return .= generateXML($k,$v,$attributes);
                $attributes = array();
            }
        }
    endforeach;
    return $return;
}
```

Love to all :)

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [XMLParser](https://github.com/jtrumbull/XMLParser) that I have been working on.

```
$xml = XMLParser::encode(array(
    'bla' => 'blub',
    'foo' => 'bar',
    'another_array' => array (
        'stack' => 'overflow',
    )
));
// @$xml instanceof SimpleXMLElement
echo $xml->asXML();
```

Would result in:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <bla>blub</bla>
    <foo>bar</foo>
    <another_array>
        <stack>overflow</stack>
    </another_array>
</root>
```

Answer (score 4):

Based on everything else here, handles numerical indices + attributes via prefixing with `@`, and could inject xml to existing nodes:

### Code

```
function simple_xmlify($arr, SimpleXMLElement $root = null, $el = 'x') {
    // based on, among others http://stackoverflow.com/a/1397164/1037948

    if(!isset($root) || null == $root) $root = new SimpleXMLElement('<' . $el . '/>');

    if(is_array($arr)) {
        foreach($arr as $k => $v) {
            // special: attributes
            if(is_string($k) && $k[0] == '@') $root->addAttribute(substr($k, 1),$v);
            // normal: append
            else simple_xmlify($v, $root->addChild(
                    // fix 'invalid xml name' by prefixing numeric keys
                    is_numeric($k) ? 'n' . $k : $k)
                );
        }
    } else {
        $root[0] = $arr;
    }

    return $root;
}//--   fn  simple_xmlify
```

### Usage

```
// lazy declaration via "queryparam"
$args = 'hello=4&var[]=first&var[]=second&foo=1234&var[5]=fifth&var[sub][]=sub1&var[sub][]=sub2&var[sub][]=sub3&var[@name]=the-name&var[@attr2]=something-else&var[sub][@x]=4.356&var[sub][@y]=-9.2252';
$q = array();
parse_str($val, $q);

$xml = simple_xmlify($q); // dump $xml, or...
$result = get_formatted_xml($xml); // see below
```

### Result

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<x>
  <hello>4</hello>
  <var name="the-name" attr2="something-else">
    <n0>first</n0>
    <n1>second</n1>
    <n5>fifth</n5>
    <sub x="4.356" y="-9.2252">
      <n0>sub1</n0>
      <n1>sub2</n1>
      <n2>sub3</n2>
    </sub>
  </var>
  <foo>1234</foo>
</x>
```

### Bonus: Formatting XML

```
function get_formatted_xml(SimpleXMLElement $xml, $domver = null, $preserveWhitespace = true, $formatOutput = true) {
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191167/format-output-of-simplexml-asxml

    // create new wrapper, so we can get formatting options
    $dom = new DOMDocument($domver);
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = $preserveWhitespace;
    $dom->formatOutput = $formatOutput;
    // now import the xml (converted to dom format)
    /*
    $ix = dom_import_simplexml($xml);
    $ix = $dom->importNode($ix, true);
    $dom->appendChild($ix);
    */
    $dom->loadXML($xml->asXML());

    // print
    return $dom->saveXML();
}//--   fn  get_formatted_xml
```

Comment: An updated version that repeats as child elements rather than numerical tags: https://github.com/zaus/forms-3rdparty-xpost/blob/75fb43cd4eb421b3736d8b816710955fadac1371/forms-3rdparty-xpost.php#L253

Answer (score 3):

IF the array is associative and keyed correctly, it would probably be easier to turn it into xml first. Something like:

```
  function array2xml ($array_item) {
    $xml = '';
    foreach($array_item as $element => $value)
    {
        if (is_array($value))
        {
            $xml .= "<$element>".array2xml($value)."</$element>";
        }
        elseif($value == '')
        {
            $xml .= "<$element />";
        }
        else
        {
            $xml .= "<$element>".htmlentities($value)."</$element>";
        }
    }
    return $xml;
}

$simple_xml = simplexml_load_string(array2xml($assoc_array));
```

The other route would be to create your basic xml first, like

```
$simple_xml = simplexml_load_string("<array></array>");
```

and then for each part of your array, use something similar to my text creating loop and instead use the simplexml functions "addChild" for each node of the array.

I'll try that out later and update this post with both versions.

Comment: That bit where I mentioned "<array></array>" made me realize that the string version needs something similar. Basically the array has to have one node on the very outside. Let me sleep on the whole thing, I'll have something that catches that initial error right off.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a function that did the trick for me:

Just call it with something like

```
echo arrayToXml("response",$arrayIWantToConvert);
function arrayToXml($thisNodeName,$input){
        if(is_numeric($thisNodeName))
            throw new Exception("cannot parse into xml. remainder :".print_r($input,true));
        if(!(is_array($input) || is_object($input))){
            return "<$thisNodeName>$input</$thisNodeName>";
        }
        else{
            $newNode="<$thisNodeName>";
            foreach($input as $key=>$value){
                if(is_numeric($key))
                    $key=substr($thisNodeName,0,strlen($thisNodeName)-1);
                $newNode.=arrayToXml3($key,$value);
            }
            $newNode.="</$thisNodeName>";
            return $newNode;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I found this solution similar to the original problem

```
<?php

$test_array = array (
  'bla' => 'blub',
  'foo' => 'bar',
  'another_array' => array (
    'stack' => 'overflow',
  ),
);

class NoSimpleXMLElement extends SimpleXMLElement {
 public function addChild($name,$value) {
  parent::addChild($value,$name);
 }
}
$xml = new NoSimpleXMLElement('<root/>');
array_walk_recursive($test_array, array ($xml, 'addChild'));
print $xml->asXML();
```

Answer (score 3):

Most of the above answers are correct. However, I came up with this answer which solves the array_walk_recursive compatibility issue and also the numerical keys problem. It also passed all the tests I made:

```
function arrayToXML(Array $array, SimpleXMLElement &$xml) {

    foreach($array as $key => $value) {

        // None array
        if (!is_array($value)) {
            (is_numeric($key)) ? $xml->addChild("item$key", $value) : $xml->addChild($key, $value);
            continue;
        }   

        // Array
        $xmlChild = (is_numeric($key)) ? $xml->addChild("item$key") : $xml->addChild($key);
        arrayToXML($value, $xmlChild);
    }
}
```

I have also added a test class for this which you may find useful:

```
class ArrayToXmlTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    public function setUp(){ }
    public function tearDown(){ }

    public function testFuncExists() {
        $this->assertTrue(function_exists('arrayToXML'));
    }

    public function testFuncReturnsXml() {
        $array = array(
            'name' => 'ardi',
            'last_name' => 'eshghi',
            'age' => 31,
            'tel' => '0785323435'
        );

        $xmlEl =  new SimpleXMLElement('<root/>');
        arrayToXml($array, $xmlEl);

        $this->assertTrue($xmlEl instanceOf SimpleXMLElement);
    }

    public function testAssocArrayToXml() {

        $array = array(
            'name' => 'ardi',
            'last_name' => 'eshghi',
            'age' => 31,
            'tel' => '0785323435'
        );

        $expectedXmlEl = new SimpleXMLElement('<root/>'); 
        $expectedXmlEl->addChild('name', $array['name']);
        $expectedXmlEl->addChild('last_name', $array['last_name']);
        $expectedXmlEl->addChild('age', $array['age']);
        $expectedXmlEl->addChild('tel', $array['tel']);

        $actualXmlEl =  new SimpleXMLElement('<root/>');
        arrayToXml($array, $actualXmlEl);

        $this->assertEquals($expectedXmlEl->asXML(), $actualXmlEl->asXML());
    }

    public function testNoneAssocArrayToXml() {

        $array = array(
            'ardi',
            'eshghi',
            31,
            '0785323435'
        );

        // Expected xml value
        $expectedXmlEl = new SimpleXMLElement('<root/>'); 
        foreach($array as $key => $value)
            $expectedXmlEl->addChild("item$key", $value);

        // What the function produces       
        $actualXmlEl =  new SimpleXMLElement('<root/>');
        arrayToXml($array, $actualXmlEl);

        $this->assertEquals($expectedXmlEl->asXML(), $actualXmlEl->asXML());
    }

    public function testNestedMixArrayToXml() {

        $testArray = array(
            "goal",
            "nice",
            "funny" => array(
                'name' => 'ardi',
                'tel'   =>'07415517499',
                "vary",
                "fields" => array(
                    'small',
                    'email' => 'ardi.eshghi@gmail.com'
                ),

                'good old days'

            ),

            "notes" => "come on lads lets enjoy this",
            "cast" => array(
                'Tom Cruise',
                'Thomas Muller' => array('age' => 24)
            )
        );

        // Expected xml value
        $expectedXmlEl = new SimpleXMLElement('<root/>'); 
        $expectedXmlEl->addChild('item0', $testArray[0]);
        $expectedXmlEl->addChild('item1', $testArray[1]);
        $childEl = $expectedXmlEl->addChild('funny');
        $childEl->addChild("name", $testArray['funny']['name']);
        $childEl->addChild("tel", $testArray['funny']['tel']);
        $childEl->addChild("item0", "vary");
        $childChildEl = $childEl->addChild("fields");
        $childChildEl->addChild('item0', 'small');
        $childChildEl->addChild('email', $testArray['funny']['fields']['email']);
        $childEl->addChild("item1", 'good old days');
        $expectedXmlEl->addChild('notes', $testArray['notes']);
        $childEl2 = $expectedXmlEl->addChild('cast');
        $childEl2->addChild('item0', 'Tom Cruise');
        $childChildEl2 = $childEl2->addChild('Thomas Muller');
        $childChildEl2->addChild('age', $testArray['cast']['Thomas Muller']['age']);

        // What the function produces       
        $actualXmlEl = new SimpleXMLElement('<root/>');
        arrayToXml($testArray, $actualXmlEl);

        $this->assertEquals($expectedXmlEl->asXML(), $actualXmlEl->asXML());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

other solution:

```
$marray=array(....);
$options = array(
                "encoding" => "UTF-8",
                "output_type" => "xml", 
                "version" => "simple",
                "escaping" => array("non-ascii, on-print, markup")
                );
$xmlres = xmlrpc_encode_request('root', $marray, $options);
print($xmlres);
```

Comment: This has an unexpected effect of creating RPC-style XML with stuff like methodCall, methodName, scalars and vectors, etc. It's not really converting an array into XML in the straightforward sense.

Comment: xmlrpc_encode_request function is undefined on php 7.3

Answer (score 2):

Just a edit on a function above, when a key is numeric, add a prefix "key_"

```
// initializing or creating array
$student_info = array(your array data);

// creating object of SimpleXMLElement
$xml_student_info = new SimpleXMLElement("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><student_info></student_info>");

// function call to convert array to xml
array_to_xml($student,$xml_student_info);

//saving generated xml file
$xml_student_info->asXML('file path and name');


function array_to_xml($student_info, &$xml_student_info) {
     foreach($student_info as $key => $value) {
          if(is_array($value)) {
            if(!is_numeric($key)){
                $subnode = $xml_student_info->addChild("$key");
                array_to_xml($value, $subnode);
            }
            else{
                $subnode = $xml_student_info->addChild("key_$key");
                array_to_xml($value, $subnode);
            }
          }
          else {
               if(!is_numeric($key)){
                    $xml_student_info->addChild("$key","$value");
               }else{
                    $xml_student_info->addChild("key_$key","$value");
               }
          }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can Use the following function in you code directly,

```
    function artoxml($arr, $i=1,$flag=false){
    $sp = "";
    for($j=0;$j<=$i;$j++){
        $sp.=" ";
     }
    foreach($arr as $key=>$val){
        echo "$sp&lt;".$key."&gt;";
        if($i==1) echo "\n";
        if(is_array($val)){
            if(!$flag){echo"\n";}
            artoxml($val,$i+5);
            echo "$sp&lt;/".$key."&gt;\n";
        }else{
              echo "$val"."&lt;/".$key."&gt;\n";
         }
    }

}
```

Call the function with first argument as your array and the second argument must be 1, this will be increased for perfect indentation, and third must be true.

for example, if the array variable to be converted is $array1 then,
calling would be, the calling function should be encapsulated with `<pre>` tag.

```
  artoxml($array1,1,true);
```

Please see the page source after executing the file, because the < and > symbols won't be displayed in a html page.

Answer (score 1):

```
function toXML($data, $obj = false, $dom) {
    $is_first_level = false;
    if($obj === false) {
        $dom = new DomDocument('1.0');
        $obj = $dom;
        $is_first_level = true;
    }

    if(is_array($data)) {
        foreach($data as $key => $item) {
            $this->toXML($item, $obj->appendChild($dom->createElement($key)), $dom);
        }
    }else {
        $obj->appendChild($dom->createTextNode($data));
    }

    if($is_first_level) {
        $obj->formatOutput = true;
        return $obj->saveXML();
    }
    return $obj;
}
```

Comment: This is excellent option for creating DOMDocument xml. Thanks @Andrey

Answer (score 1):

```
function array2xml(array $data, SimpleXMLElement $object = null, $oldNodeName = 'item')
{
    if (is_null($object)) $object = new SimpleXMLElement('<root/>');
    $isNumbered = true;
    $idx = 0;
    foreach ($data as $key => $x)
        if (is_string($key) || ($idx++ != $key + 0))
            $isNumbered = false;
    foreach ($data as $key => $value)
    {   
        $attribute = preg_match('/^[0-9]/', $key . '') ? $key : null;
        $key = (is_string($key) && !preg_match('/^[0-9]/', $key . '')) ? $key : preg_replace('/s$/', '', $oldNodeName);
        if (is_array($value))
        {
            $new_object = $object->addChild($key);
            if (!$isNumbered && !is_null($attribute)) $new_object->addAttribute('id', $attribute);
            array2xml($value, $new_object, $key);
        }
        else
        {
            if (is_bool($value)) $value = $value ? 'true' : 'false';
            $node = $object->addChild($key, htmlspecialchars($value));
            if (!$isNumbered && !is_null($attribute) && !isset($node->attributes()->id))
                $node->addAttribute('id', $attribute);
        }
    }
    return $object;
}
```

This function returns for example a list of <obj>...</obj><obj>...</obj> XML tags for numeric indexes.

Input:

```
    array(
    'people' => array(
        'dog',
        'cat',
        'life' => array(
            'gum',
            'shoe',
        ),
        'fish',
    ),
    array('yeah'),
)
```

Output:

```
<root>
    <people>
        <people>dog</people>
        <people>cat</people>
        <life>
            <life>gum</life>
            <life>shoe</life>
        </life>
        <people>fish</people>
        <people>
            <people>yeah</people>
        </people>
    </people>
</root>
```

This should satisfy all common needs. Maybe you may change the 3rd line to:

```
$key = is_string($key) ? $key : $oldNodeName . '_' . $key;
```

or if you are working with plurals ending with s:

```
$key = is_string($key) ? $key : preg_replace('/s$/', '', $oldNodeName);
```

Answer (score 1):

With [**FluidXML**](https://github.com/servo-php/fluidxml) you can generate, starting from a **PHP Array**, an XML for **SimpleXML** with... just two lines of code.

```
$fluidxml  = fluidxml($array);
$simplexml = simplexml_import_dom($fluidxml->dom());
```

An example array could be

```
$array = [ 'doc' => [
              'fruit' => 'orange',
              'cake'  => [
                   '@id' => '123', 
                   '@'   => 'tiramisu' ],
              [ 'pasta' => 'matriciana' ],
              [ 'pasta' => 'boscaiola'  ]
] ];
```

https://github.com/servo-php/fluidxml

Answer (score 0):

You may use xmlrpc_encode to create a xml from array if a verbose xml is not a problem.
[www.php.net/xmlrpc_encode](http://www.php.net/xmlrpc_encode)

be careful the xml created differs in case you use associative and/or numeric keys

```
<?php
// /params/param/value/struct/member
// there is a tag "member" for each element
// "member" contains a tag "name". its value is the associative key
$xml1 = xmlrpc_encode(array('a'=>'b','c'=>'d'));
$simplexml1 = simplexml_load_string($xml1);
print_r($xml1);
print_r($simplexml1);

// /params/param/value/array/data
// there is a tag "data" for each element
// "data" doesn't contain the tag "name"
$xml2 = xmlrpc_encode(array('a','b'));
$simplexml2 = simplexml_load_string($xml2);
print_r($xml2);
print_r($simplexml2);
?>
```

Comment: This function is unsupported and, in fact, isn't provided in my builds of PHP 5.2.16 or PHP 5.3.5. (returns “PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function xmlrpc_encode()”)

Comment: you have to uncomment the following line in php.ini: extension=php_xmlrpc.dll

Comment: @w35l3y I checked my ini. It doesn't even contain that extension and I'm using v 5.3.6.

Answer (score 0):

```
function array2xml($array, $xml = false){

    if($xml === false){

        $xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version=\'1.0\' encoding=\'utf-8\'?><'.key($array).'/>');
        $array = $array[key($array)];

    }
    foreach($array as $key => $value){
        if(is_array($value)){
            $this->array2xml($value, $xml->addChild($key));
        }else{
            $xml->addChild($key, $value);
        }
    }
    return $xml->asXML();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer, cobbling together others' answers. This should correct for the failure to compensate for numeric keys:

```
function array_to_xml($array, $root, $element) {
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement("<{$root}/>");
    foreach ($array as $value) {
        $elem = $xml->addChild($element);
        xml_recurse_child($elem, $value);
    }
    return $xml;
}

function xml_recurse_child(&$node, $child) {
    foreach ($child as $key=>$value) {
        if(is_array($value)) {
            foreach ($value as $k => $v) {
                if(is_numeric($k)){
                    xml_recurse_child($node, array($key => $v));
                }
                else {
                    $subnode = $node->addChild($key);
                    xml_recurse_child($subnode, $value);
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            $node->addChild($key, $value);
        }
    }   
}
```

The `array_to_xml()` function presumes that the array is made up of numeric keys first. If your array had an initial element, you would drop the `foreach()` and `$elem` statements from the `array_to_xml()` function and just pass `$xml` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would have commented the second most voted answer, because it doesn't preserve structure and generates bad xml if there is numerically indexed inner arrays.

I developed my own version based on it, because I needed simple converter between json and xml regardless of the structure of data.  My version preserves numeric key information and structure of the original array. It creates elements for the numerically indexed values by wrapping values to value -named elements with key-attribute that contains numerical key.

For example

`array('test' => array(0 => 'some value', 1 => 'other'))`

converts to

`<test><value key="0">some value</value><value key="1">other</value></test>`

My version of array_to_xml -function (hope it helps somebody :)

```
function array_to_xml($arr, &$xml) {
    foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
        if(is_array($value)) {
            if(!is_numeric($key)){
                $subnode = $xml->addChild("$key");
            } else {
                $subnode = $xml->addChild("value");
                $subnode->addAttribute('key', $key);                    
            }
            array_to_xml($value, $subnode);
        }
        else {
            if (is_numeric($key)) {
                $xml->addChild("value", $value)->addAttribute('key', $key);
            } else {
                $xml->addChild("$key",$value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whole XML structure is defined in $data Array:

```
function array2Xml($data, $xml = null)
{
    if (is_null($xml)) {
        $xml = simplexml_load_string('<' . key($data) . '/>');
        $data = current($data);
        $return = true;
    }
    if (is_array($data)) {
        foreach ($data as $name => $value) {
            array2Xml($value, is_numeric($name) ? $xml : $xml->addChild($name));
        }
    } else {
        $xml->{0} = $data;
    }
    if (!empty($return)) {
        return $xml->asXML();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you work in magento and you have this type of associative array

```
$test_array = array (
    '0' => array (
            'category_id' => '582',
            'name' => 'Surat',
            'parent_id' => '565',
            'child_id' => '567',
            'active' => '1',
            'level' => '6',
            'position' => '17'
    ),

    '1' => array (
            'category_id' => '567', 
            'name' => 'test',
            'parent_id' => '0',
            'child_id' => '576',
            'active' => '0',
            'level' => '0',
            'position' => '18'
    ),
);
```

then this is best to convert associative array to xml format.Use this code in controller file.

```
$this->loadLayout(false);
//header ("content-type: text/xml");
$this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-Type','text/xml');
$this->renderLayout();

$clArr2xml = new arr2xml($test_array, 'utf-8', 'listdata');
$output = $clArr2xml->get_xml();
print $output; 

class arr2xml
{
var $array = array();
var $xml = '';
var $root_name = '';
var $charset = '';

public function __construct($array, $charset = 'utf-8', $root_name = 'root')
{
    header ("content-type: text/xml");
    $this->array = $array;
    $this->root_name = $root_name;
    $this->charset = $charset;

    if (is_array($array) && count($array) > 0) {
        $this->struct_xml($array);

    } else {
        $this->xml .= "no data";
    }
}

public function struct_xml($array)
{
    foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
        if (is_array($v)) {
            $tag = ereg_replace('^[0-9]{1,}', 'item', $k); // replace numeric key in array to 'data'
            $this->xml .= "<$tag>";
            $this->struct_xml($v);
            $this->xml .= "</$tag>";
        } else {
            $tag = ereg_replace('^[0-9]{1,}', 'item', $k); // replace numeric key in array to 'data'
            $this->xml .= "<$tag><![CDATA[$v]]></$tag>";
        }
    }
}

public function get_xml()
{

    $header = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"" . $this->charset . "\"?><" . $this->root_name . ">";
    $footer = "</" . $this->root_name . ">";

    return $header . $this->xml . $footer;
}
}
```

I hope it helps to all.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Structered array for XML convertion.
$data_array = array(
  array(
    '#xml_tag' => 'a',
    '#xml_value' => '',
    '#tag_attributes' => array(
      array(
        'name' => 'a_attr_name',
        'value' => 'a_attr_value',
      ),
    ),
    '#subnode' => array(
      array(
        '#xml_tag' => 'aa',
        '#xml_value' => 'aa_value',
        '#tag_attributes' => array(
          array(
            'name' => 'aa_attr_name',
            'value' => 'aa_attr_value',
          ),
        ),
        '#subnode' => FALSE,
      ),
    ),
  ),
  array(
    '#xml_tag' => 'b',
    '#xml_value' => 'b_value',
    '#tag_attributes' => FALSE,
    '#subnode' => FALSE,
  ),
  array(
    '#xml_tag' => 'c',
    '#xml_value' => 'c_value',
    '#tag_attributes' => array(
      array(
        'name' => 'c_attr_name',
        'value' => 'c_attr_value',
      ),
      array(
        'name' => 'c_attr_name_1',
        'value' => 'c_attr_value_1',
      ),
    ),
    '#subnode' => array(
      array(
        '#xml_tag' => 'ca',  
        '#xml_value' => 'ca_value',
        '#tag_attributes' => FALSE,
        '#subnode' => array(
          array(
            '#xml_tag' => 'caa',
            '#xml_value' => 'caa_value',
            '#tag_attributes' => array(
              array(
                'name' => 'caa_attr_name',
                'value' => 'caa_attr_value',
              ),
            ),
            '#subnode' => FALSE,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);


// creating object of SimpleXMLElement
$xml_object = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><student_info></student_info>');


// function call to convert array to xml
array_to_xml($data_array, $xml_object);

// saving generated xml file
$xml_object->asXML('/tmp/test.xml');

/**
 * Converts an structured PHP array to XML.
 *
 * @param Array $data_array
 *   The array data for converting into XML.
 * @param Object $xml_object
 *   The SimpleXMLElement Object
 *
 * @see https://gist.github.com/drupalista-br/9230016
 * 
 */
function array_to_xml($data_array, &$xml_object) {
  foreach($data_array as $node) {
    $subnode = $xml_object->addChild($node['#xml_tag'], $node['#xml_value']);

    if ($node['#tag_attributes']) {
      foreach ($node['#tag_attributes'] as $tag_attributes) {
        $subnode->addAttribute($tag_attributes['name'], $tag_attributes['value']); 
      }
    }

    if ($node['#subnode']) {
      array_to_xml($node['#subnode'], $subnode);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this through DOM also. Please see below code.

```
<?php

$el = array();
$command = array();

$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$dom->formatOutput = true;

$xml_array = [
    'root'=>[
    'Good guy' => [
        'name' => [
            '_cdata' => 'Luke Skywalker'
        ],
        'weapon' => 'Lightsaber'
    ],
    'Bad guy' => [
        'name' => 'Sauron',
        'weapon' => 'Evil Eye'
    ]
        ]
];

convert_xml($xml_array);

if(!empty($el))
{
    $dom->appendChild(end($el));
}

echo $dom->saveXML();

?>

<?php

 function convert_xml($Xml)
{
    global $el, $dom;

        foreach($Xml as $id=>$val)
        {
            if(is_numeric($id))
            {
                $id = "Item".($id);
            }

            $id = str_replace(' ', '-', strtolower($id));

            if(is_array($val))
            {
                $ele = $dom->createElement($id);
                array_push($el, $ele);
                convert_xml($val);
            }
            else
            {
                $ele = $dom->createElement($id, $val);

                if(!empty($el))
                {
                    $com = end($el)->appendChild($ele);
                }
                else
                {
                    $dom->appendChild($ele);
                }

            }
        }

        if(sizeof($el) > 1)
        {
            $child = end($el);
            $com = prev($el)->appendChild($child);
            array_pop($el);
        }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think all the above solutions are nice but what i see so far, it not really creates an exact well formed XML because of ARRAY Keys with $my_array[main_node][multiple_values][] = array('id' => '1') are then converted into

```
    <main_node>
       <multiple_values>
         <0>
           <id>1 test</id>
         </0>
       </multiple_values>
       <multiple_values>
         <1>
          <id>2 test</id>
         </1>
       </multiple_values>
    </main_node>
```

which is a problem on a XML Parser side...

```
I should be like this:

    <main_node>
     <multiple_values>
      <id>1 test</id>
     </multiple_values>
     <multiple_values>
      <id>2 test</id>
     </multiple_values>
    </main_node>
```

So if you parse this by load_simple_xml...you will exactly the same array/object structure back.

My function also auto create the correct root node automatic.

```
    // Code to convert php array to xml document 20211112
    function array2xml(array $data, $xml_class_obj = '', $group_by_parent_allowed = '', $options = array())
        {   
            
            if(!$xml_class_obj) :
                $is_root = 1;
                $xml_class_obj = new XMLWriter();
                $xml_class_obj->openMemory();
                $xml_class_obj->setIndent(TRUE);
                $xml_class_obj->setIndentString('   ');
                if($options['encoding'] != '')  $xml_class_obj->startDocument('1.0', $options['encoding']);
                else                                                        $xml_class_obj->startDocument('1.0');
            endif;
            
            foreach ($data as $key => $value) {

                if (is_array($value)) { // IS ARRAY

                    // check if allow below keys are int, if yes group them to same parent tree
                    $group_by_parent = $key;
                    foreach(array_keys($value) as $c_keys) :
                        if(!is_int($c_keys)) $group_by_parent = '';
                    endforeach;

                    if(empty($group_by_parent)) $xml_class_obj->startElement($key); 
                    if($group_by_parent_allowed != '') $xml_class_obj->startElement($group_by_parent_allowed);
                    
                    $this->array2xml($value, $xml_class_obj, $group_by_parent, $options);
                    
                    if(empty($group_by_parent)) $xml_class_obj->endElement();  

                } else { // IS VALUE
                    
                    if(is_string($value)) :
                        $xml_class_obj->startElement($key);
                        $xml_class_obj->writeCData($value);         
                        $xml_class_obj->endElement();           
                    else :
                        $xml_class_obj->writeElement($key, $value); 
                    endif;

                }

            } // foreach
            
            if($group_by_parent_allowed != '')  $xml_class_obj->endElement(); 
            
            if($is_root == 1) :
            
                $xml_class_obj->endDocument();
                return $xml_class_obj->outputMemory();
            else :              
                return $xml_class_obj;                  
            endif;
              
        }  
    
    // usage
    $ary_new_xml = array();
    $ary_new_xml['order']['customer']['customerid'] = '123456'; 
    $ary_new_xml['order']['customer']['customertype'] = 15; 
            
    $ary_new_xml['order']['orderprio'] = 2; 
            
    $ary_new_xml['order']['orderpos'][] = array('sku' => 9999910001111, 'quantity' => 3);           
    $ary_new_xml['order']['orderpos'][] = array('sku' => 9999910002222, 'quantity' => 1); 
            
echo array2xml($ary_new_xml,'','',array('enconding' => 'UTF-8'));
```

Results in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<order>
   <customer>
      <customerid>82936639</customerid>
      <customertype>15</customertype>
   </customer>
   <orderprio>2</orderprio>
   <orderpos>
      <sku>9999910001111</sku>
      <quantity>3</quantity>
   </orderpos>
   <orderpos>
      <sku>9999910002222</sku>
      <quantity>1</quantity>
   </orderpos>
</order>
```

I hope this helps somebody out there ;)

Answer (score -1):

the following deals with namespaces.  In this case,  you construct the wrapper to include the namespace definitions, and pass it into the function. use a colon to identify the namespace.

Test Array

```
$inarray = [];
$inarray['p:apple'] = "red";
$inarray['p:pear'] = "green";
$inarray['p:peach'] = "orange";
$inarray['p1:grocers'] = ['p1:local' => "cheap", 'p1:imported' => "expensive"];


$xml = new SimpleXMLElement( '<p:wrapper xmlns:p="http://namespace.org/api" xmlns:p1="http://namespace.org/api2 /> ');

array_to_xml($xml,$inarray); 




function array_to_xml(SimpleXMLElement $object, array $data)
{   
    $nslist = $object->getDocNamespaces();

    foreach ($data as $key => $value)
    {   
        $nspace = null;
        $keyparts = explode(":",$key,2);
        if ( count($keyparts)==2) 
            $nspace = $nslist[$keyparts[0]];

        if (is_array($value))
        {   
            $key = is_numeric($key) ? "item$key" : $key;
            $new_object = $object->addChild($key,null,$nspace);
            array_to_xml($new_object, $value);
        }   
        else
        {   
            $key = is_numeric($key) ? "item$key" : $key;
            $object->addChild($key, $value,$nspace);
        }   
    }   
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use Mustache Template Engine and make a Template like:

```
{{#RECEIVER}}
<RECEIVER>
    <COMPANY>{{{COMPANY}}}</COMPANY>
    <CONTACT>{{{CONTACT}}}</CONTACT>
    <ADDRESS>{{{ADDRESS}}}</ADDRESS>
    <ZIP>{{ZIP}}</ZIP>
    <CITY>{{{CITY}}}</CITY>
</RECEIVER>
{{/RECEIVER}}
{{#DOC}}
<DOC>
    <TEXT>{{{TEXT}}}</TEXT>
    <NUMBER>{{{NUMBER}}}</NUMBER>
</DOC>
{{/DOC}}
```

Use it like this in PHP:

```
require_once( __DIR__ .'/../controls/Mustache/Autoloader.php' );
Mustache_Autoloader::register();
$oMustache = new Mustache_Engine();
$sTemplate = implode( '', file( __DIR__ ."/xml.tpl" ));
$return = $oMustache->render($sTemplate, $res);
echo($return);
```